# selecting a single field from database table using php and ajax shows an error as undefined index

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, web-services

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#display').click(function(){

        $.ajax({ 
            type:"GET",
            url:"new1.php",
            datatype:"html",

        async: "false",
            success:function(response)
        {
                $("#show").html(response);
          }


       });

    });

});

```
</head>
```

```
<input type="text" name="mono" method="post" class="tbox" >
<input type="button" name="submit" id="display" value="check">

<div id="show"> </div>
```

new1.php

```
<?php

    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";


      $vah = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
 echo "Connected MySQL ";

  mysql_select_db("students",$vah);

 $pin =$_POST['mono'];
    //  $pin = isset($_POST['mono']) ? $_POST['mono']: '';


  $qry= "SELECT *FROM shop WHERE pin='$pin'";
  $res= mysql_query($qry);

  echo "<table border='1' >
        <tr>
        <td align=center> <b>pin</b></td>
        <td align=center><b>service</b></td>
        <td align=center><b>days</b></td>           
        </td> ";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res))

        {   
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align=center>$data[0]</td>";
            echo "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
            echo "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        } 
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Comment: Please post your error.

Comment: `$qry= "SELECT *FROM shop WHERE pin='$pin'";` You can get an SQL Injection here ;)

Comment: At first you need "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE pin='$pin'", (space before FROM), at second  I think you do not send $_POST['mono'] from jquery

Comment: You are declaring type as GET but getting variable using $_POST['mono']; where are you passing variable mono?

Comment: if i change qry as select*from table_name it shows result , but i need to show only one field

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: mono in D:\xamp\htdocs\vahab\pincode\new1.php on line 13   this is the errror @ akram fares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your error may solve after updating your new.php like the following:

```
<?php

    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";


      $vah = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
 echo "Connected MySQL ";

  mysql_select_db("students",$vah);

 $pin =$_POST['mono'];
    //  $pin = isset($_POST['mono']) ? $_POST['mono']: '';


  $qry= "SELECT *FROM shop WHERE pin='$pin'";
  $res= mysql_query($qry);

  $html = "<table border='1' >
        <tr>
        <td align=center> <b>pin</b></td>
        <td align=center><b>service</b></td>
        <td align=center><b>days</b></td>           
        </td> ";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($res))

        {   
            $html += "<tr>";
            $html += "<td align=center>$data[0]</td>";
            $html += "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
            $html += "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";
            $html += "</tr>";
        } 
        $html += "</table>";
        echo $html;
        ?>
```

Comment: it shows Notice: Undefined index: mono in D:\xamp\htdocs\vahab\pincode\new1.php on line 13
0